# Spring CSS sometimes loading bootstrap but not my CSS

Tags: java, html, css, spring, thymeleaf

I'm having quite a mistery and I have no idea where to start searching or what for. Problem is that my edit page for selected item does not load css, while practically same page for adding the same item loads just fine. I went to check differences with diff check just to make sure and I can't find it. Is it possible because it is /id of item that somehow CSS is not getting loaded?

To be more clear. On edit page Bootstrap does load but my CSS does not. If needed, let me know if I need to provide pictures.

Controller add part:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/newcontactor", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView contactorFormNew() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("ContactorFormNew");

    Contactor c = new Contactor();
    List<Manufacturer> miro = serviceManu.listManufacturers();

    mav.addObject("contactor", c);
    mav.addObject("listManufacturers", miro);
    return mav;
}
```

Controller edit part:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/contactors/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView fuseForm(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("ContactorForm");

    Contactor c = serviceContactor.getContactorById(id);

    List<Manufacturer> miro = serviceManu.listManufacturers();

    for (int i = 0; i < miro.size(); i++) {
        if (miro.get(i).getName().equals(c.getManufacturer().getName())) {
            miro.add(0, miro.get(i));
            miro.remove(i + 1);
        }
    }
    mav.addObject("contactor", c);
    mav.addObject("listManufacturers", miro);

    return mav;}
```

Edit html (not loading CSS):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
<title>Contactor Editor</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css"></link>

</head>
```

Add html(loading css):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
<title>Contactor New</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css"></link>

</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's looking for your css in the wrong page when editing (because of the extra `/` in the url when editing:

On `/newcontactor` it's looking for the CSS in /Style.css

On `/contactors/{id}` it's looking for the CSS in /contactors/Style.css

I think changing `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css"></link>` to `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/Style.css}"></link>` should fix this. (This does depend slightly on how your context/servlets are setup.)

(And you should be debugging this kind of stuff by watching the network tab in your browser's developer tools.  The network tab would clearly show a 404 when trying to load Style.css.)

Comment: you are absolutely correct, I forgot to update the question. adding th:href with my style has fixed the problem